# Mapping data from Object of Objects in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, amazon-web-services, axios

I am fetching some data from an api and I want to map through it inorder to get all the values inside . But I am unable to do so . Need some help.
Here's the data :

```
{
'id:5': {
    1: {
        coinid: 5,
        coinname: 'Chainlink',
        publishedAt: '2021-06-24T11:10:54Z',
        source: 'Cointelegraph',
        title:
            'asset manager qr launches bitcoin etf on brazilian stock exchange',
        description:
            'in contrast to hashdexs crypto etf product qr asset managements product provides exposure to bitcoin exclusively',
        url: 'https://cointelegraph.com/news/asset-manager-qr-launches-bitcoin-etf-on-brazilian-stock-exchange',
    },
    2: {
        coinid: 5,
        coinname: 'Chainlink',
        publishedAt: '2021-06-24T13:39:56Z',
        source: 'Business Wire',
        title:
            'truefi announces new integrations with binance chainlink and sushiswap further embedding into the defi ecosystem',
        description:
            'san franciscobusiness wire binancetrusttoken announces a suite of deep defi integrations designed to make the truefi platform safer more robust and more lucrative for its users',
        url: 'https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20210624005642/en/TrueFi-Announces-New-Integrations-With-Bina',
    },
}
```

and here is my code for fetching api ( I have to unescape the api data coz it was in escaped form) :

```
    const fetchNews = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
            'https://h3iiccq04i.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev',
        );
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        // setNewsData(JSON.parse(data));
        setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
};
```

here the newsData is an object which I have to map and get all the values such as  coinname ,url ,etc . Any help would be really appreciated .

Comment: `{Object.values(newsData["id:5"]).map(...)}` (your actual question is: "how to I get the values of an Object in array form?")

Answer (score 1):

We could use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get in an array with all the object values and then iterate over it with a map.

```
const dataArray = Object.values(data['id:5'])
dataArray.map(...)
```